# How to solve php5-sqlite unmet dependencies (php5-common) error on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: php, sqlite, ubuntu

I am trying to install php5-sqlite on Ubuntu 14.04, but this error occurs:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-sqlite : Depends: php5-common (= 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.4) but 5.5.16+dfsg-1+deb.sury.org~precise+2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I resolve this error? I have upgraded my Ubuntu server from 12.04 to the current 14.04 previously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've met the same problem today. There are two ways to resolve it:

- use `aptitude` to help you resolve all the dependency problems,

  `sudo aptitude install php5-sqlite`

  if you haven't install `aptitude`, install it:

  `sudo apt-get install aptitude`

  it will give you the option to downgrade the library file to an earlier version
- download the proper version of `php5-common` (and related packages if necessary) from [launchpad](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/183997856/php5-common_5.5.9%2Bdfsg-1ubuntu4.4_amd64.deb), use `dpkg -i package` to install it, then install `php5-sqlite`.

I highly recommend the second approach.

Answer (score 3):

the [accepted answer from **@jfly**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26232836/how-to-solve-php5-sqlite-unmet-dependencies-php5-common-error-on-ubuntu-14-04#26252771) didn't work for me, however, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540423/libapache2-mod-php5-depends-php5-common#540428) helped resolve the issue by first uninstalling all the old php packages and then reinstalling them.

remove:

```
sudo apt-get remove php5 php5-common php5-mysql php5-xmlrpc php5-cgi php5-curl php5-gd php5-cli php5-fpm php-apc php-pear php5-dev php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-sqlite
```

install:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 php5-mysql php-pear php5-gd  php5-mcrypt php5-curl php5-sqlite
```

Answer (score 0):

This means you have one source file not upgraded to the latest repo.

Either use `apt-pinning` to tell apt which source to prefere or make sure all your sources are up to date. You might need to do both :-)

Please also note that this question is rather off-topic on SO because 1. it doesn't involve programing 2. [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com) is the stackexchange platform for ubuntu questions.